# My printf format specifier will not compile due to the format of my string, along with the arguments being used

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to write a small program that will convert a person's, or any height from imperial to metric but I am getting the compiler error is telling me: "data argument is not used by format string"

```
    printf("Enter your height with just a space between feet and inches: ");
scanf("%2s", "%f", &ft, &in);
ft = in / 12;
double delta = (ft * 30.48);
double rem = in * 2.54;
double calc = delta + rem;
printf("Your height is %f ft and %.1f in\n", delta, calc);

return (0);
```

Comment: Is it your `scanf` or your `printf` format string that the compiler is complaining about?  (Your `printf` call looks okay to me, but your `scanf` call has grave difficulties.)

Comment: I suspect you want something more like `scanf("%d %d", &ft, &in);`.  But your code has other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of bugs in your code.

- `ft` (feet) normally a float variable, use `%f` instead of `%s`. Also give all format specifier in single double quotes like `"%f %f"`. Probably you want like this

  `scanf("%2f %f", &ft, &in);`
- you should check whether `scanf()` was success or not by checking the return value of `scanf()`, read manual page by typing `man 3 scanf` on command prompt or see here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html . for e.g
   `int ret = scanf("%2f %f", &ft, &in);`

Here is the sample code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
        float ft = 0, in = 0; /* don't keep uninitialized local variable */
        printf("Enter your height with just a space between feet and inches: ");
        scanf("%2f %f", &ft, &in);
        ft = in / 12;
        double delta = (ft * 30.48);
        double rem = in * 2.54;
        double calc = delta + rem;
        printf("Your height is %f ft and %.1f in\n", delta, calc);
        return 0;
}
```

Also compile your program with `-Wall` flag like `gcc -Wall test.c` and don't ignore warning, solve them. Better treat all warnings as error by compiling with `-Wstrict-prototypes -Werror` so that there could be less chance of bugs. for e.g

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror test.c
```

And finally learn how to debug a small code https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: But you wouldn't want to enter fractional feet, if you're also entering inches.

Comment: Yes agree @SteveSummit I didn't think as much as you did. You are genius.

Comment: By the way I didn't got a way to communicate with you . But I like very much your book `"C Programming Faqs: Steve Summit"`  It helped me lot. Thanks @SteveSummit  & I'm from India & you are very famous among young software engineers here.

Comment: And there's not much point in making the user enter the length in feet if the next thing that you do is throw that value away with `ft = in / 12;`.  (It's a problem in the original code too.)